# Android: ListView can't get full layout_height in ScrollView

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, scrollview, fill-parent

I have two questions: 

 - How to get a dynamic height(fill_parent, match_parent) for my ListView? If I write "layout_height: fill_parent" it's not really working 

 - How can I get a solution without ScrollView, only with the ListView? (Without ScrollView my scrollbar is too far away from right site.)

Greets Robin

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e7e7e7">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#bfbfbf"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="05.07.2014"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_header"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="431dp"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Why do you put a ListView in a ScrollView? it's definately a **bad practice**. A ListView is scrollable by itself...

Comment: You can also avoid using a LinearLayout and set the ListView's height to match_parent.

Comment: There is no need of `ScrollView`

Comment: to fix the scrollbar padding problem use:
`android:clipToPadding="false"` and 
`android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"` https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/LpAA7q4jw9M

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need of `ScrollView`:

You may getting warning while designing like:

> The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another
>   vertically scrolling widget (ListView)

You can achieve your design using this also:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e7e7e7" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#bfbfbf"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="05.07.2014"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_header"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="15dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the header view should probably be in a new xml file, and use `addHeaderView` to set it.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK No, you don't need to use `addHeaderView` (nor `addFooterView`). If you have a design that `already includes` a Header (and/or a Footer).